# Play webview video when home button pressed

Tags: android, webview

I am creating an app that plays videos from website in phone. Now I have one problem, that when user press home button video automatically pauses. How to prevent app from pausing videos?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Enable Javascript

    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState( WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    // Use remote resource
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://some.website");

    // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
   // mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click(); })()");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {
        // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('play').click(); })()"); }
    });

    // Use local resource
    // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue creating MediaService for music play.